# Compare two XML Files and show differences b/w them and Update file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to compare two xml files and show difference between them and update file.

Kindly suggest me tricks or tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

I found javascript library which compare at client side [jsdifflib](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib#overview)

Answer (score 1):

Try Xmldiffpatch. It's a library for diffing Xml, but hasn't been updated in ages though:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Another product that specializes in XML differencing and comparison is DeltaXML. It's very comprehensive, but not free.